# Is there a way to combine two dataframes with different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes(worked_data_year & worked_data ) that are slices of a larger dataframe`data`. The 2 slices have transformations performed on them using the `groupby()` and `agg` functions to create a similarly named column in both slices. An example is the code below:

```
worked_data_year = data.groupby(['CONTRACT_ID','_YEAR','LINE_OF_B'], as_index=False)['revenue'].agg("sum")
worked_data = data.groupby(['CONTRACT_ID','LINE_OF_B'], as_index=False)['revenue'].agg("sum")
```

What im trying to do is use the revenue values for each contract and line of business(overal irrespective of year) from the second worked_data, to replace the different revenue values for similar contracts & LOB in the worked_data_year.

I tried using join, merge and concat to do this but i get errors for trying to merge 2 differntly sized data frames. I tried using a for loop but that didnt work as well

**Edits**

A sample table for the df without the year column(7048,3):
[DF that doesn't have the year column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI3Lq.png)

and a table that does have the year column(29084,4):[DF with a year column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz3sl.png)

Comment: It's hard to give advice without seeing the dataframes and/or specific error messages. Try to provide a small and reproducible example that exhibits the error that you see.